# Calculating Simple Functions of Discrete Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Say I have a random variable $X$ that has some distribution (e.g. the value obtained when rolling a standard dice). I'm trying to find out whether the probability distributions of **functions** of that variable are calculated by simply taking the probability for $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$.... $x_n$ and assigning them to $f(x_1),~ f(x_2),\dots,~f(x_n)$ or whether there is a more complicated process, and that depends perhaps on the functions and types, number of etc r.v.'s themselves?

For example, say the player of a game scores points based on the value of the above dice they roll (whose r.v. is $X$), according to:

$$f(X) = X^2 + 2X + 2 $$

For the dice: $X = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ or $6$. And of course $\Bbb P(X = x_{1-6}) = 1/6$

Calculating $f(X)$ for the dice's values, the possible points you can score are: $5, 10, 17, 26, 37$ and $50$.

Is then the probability distribution for the points you can score simply: $$\Bbb P(f(X) = 5) = 1/6; \Bbb P(f(X)=10) = 1/6,\dots, \Bbb P(f(X) = 50) = 1/6 $$? Would it be accurate too to say that the score $f(X)$ is itself a random variable?

I'm hoping to extend this concept to things like the addition of different r.v.'s - i.e. to understand what it means to add two r.v.'s $X + Y$ - but I've heard this is much more complicated, so I thought I'd start with this.

Many thanks for all your insight, really appreciate it.

Comment: Basic approach is sound for a discrete random variable (taking finite or countably many values). You have to be careful if $f$ is not 1-to-1 [for example if two values of $X$ produce one value of $f(X)$]. // A different approach is usually necessary for continuous random variables. (For example, the square of a normal random variable.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is indeed how it works in this case, and that $f(X)$ is indeed a random variable in its own right.

To see this more clearly, we can calculate
\begin{align} \\
\ \Bbb P(f(X)=5) & = \Bbb P(X^2+2X+2=5) \\
\ & = \Bbb P(X^2+2X-3=0) \\
\ & = \Bbb P((X+3)(X-1)=0) \\
\ & = \Bbb P(X=-3)+\Bbb P(X=1) \\
\ & = 0 + 1/6 \\
\ & = 1/6
\end{align}

Similarly for the others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a function of a random variable is a random variable as well. There are a few cases where the function can "remove all randomness" (e.g. $X$ is $-1$ or $1$ with equal probability and $f(X)=X^2$), but even in these cases $f(X)$ can still be considered a random variable.

Your probabilities for $f(X)$ with the die roll example are correct. Generally, for a discrete random variable the calculation is identical: you just plug in the $X$ values to get the $f(X)$ values and carry over the same numerical probability for each outcome. Of course you have to be a little careful if multiple $X$ values give the same function output, and, in this case, you need to combine the probabilities appropriately.

There is a general result for continuous random variables. You need to know calculus to apply this method though. See the Wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables). You have to be careful with functions that don't satisfy certain properties (they need to be one-to-one), e.g. $f(X)=X^2$ can be tricky.

For two random variables (or three more random variables, and so on), you need the concept of a [joint probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution). This can become more complicated though. For multiple discrete random variables, you can generally calculate the probabilities similarly to the way you have already done.

Comment: (+1) But maybe _one-to-one_ instead of _monotone_ in 3rd paragraph?

Comment: I did think to write one-to-one. I was actually thinking strictly monotone and continuously differentiable for the simple case. How about I just edit it to say "certain properties, e.g. one-to-one"? As I think the answer at this level shouldn't include too many technical details.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** Consider $Y = g(X) = (X - 2.5)^2,$ just to see what happens when two $X$-values can yield a single $Y$-value. Here is a graph of the four $Y$-values and their
probabilities. (Horizontal green lines at $0, 1/6, 2/6.$)

[image]

Also, notice that $E(X) = 3.5,$ but $E(Y) = 47/12 \approx 3.9167,$ *not* $(3.5-2.5)^2 = 1.$